# Proposition Translation

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[image]

For this, I got (not p and not s)---> not T.

Here is my thinking. The word unless is giving me a hard time so I used an anolgy and made a random sentence.

"Open the door unless you are sick" = " Open the door if you are not sick" = "If you are not sick, then open the door".

My thinking could be totally wrong, so I'm interested in your input. The solutions have not been posted  so i want to know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Unless* is usually transalted as $\lor$ ("or").

Thus, your thinking is correct :

> "Open the door unless you are sick" must be "Open the door or you are sick", i.e. (due to the equivalence between $p \lor q$ and $\lnot p \to q$) "If you are not sick, then open the door".